# Shortcut for inserting elements in Netbeans

Tags: html, netbeans, automation, code-formatting

Writing a webpage requires a lot of creating divs. Is there a plugin that would allow me to type `div.row.big` and hit tab to create the following?

```
<div class="row big">

</div>
```

Or `li#active` for

```
<li id="active"></li>
```

I have seen this done in Sublime Text 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for?

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48315/emmet